# Just generate an import library (.lib) without linking the DLL

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll, circular-dependency

I got a legacy product with circular dependencies among its DLLs.
So I'm now thinking of a 2-step build:

1. Just generate the import libraries and don't link the DLLs
2. Having all the import libraries, link the DLLs

Is there a command line to `MSBuild` or `DevEnv` to just generate the import libraries and return success error code if the sources just compile?
This is important for Jenkins: I don't want the build to fail in the first step if I do the linking. I want some command which just checks that the sources do compile in the 1st step and returns success in this case, and leaves an import library ready.

Comment: Create a target that's a library, then use that library in other builds.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no standard project target to do this but the lib.exe tool can generate a .lib from a .def without actually needing the associated code.

Comment: See if this helps: [Mutual Imports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/mutual-imports)

Comment: [Using an Import Library and Export File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/using-an-import-library-and-export-file?view=vs-2017)

Comment: so you need have the *def* file and than run `LINK.EXE /lib /MACHINE:[*] /DEF:my_exports.def`